# Autofill error on Range Class

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add 2 columns with formulas and autofill down to the last row, but I'm getting an

> Autofill method of range class failed

when running the code. It breaks at the line that starts with `Activecell.Autofill`

```
Sub addColumnsandChange()
Dim LastRow As Integer

'Finds the value of the last row
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Selection.EntireColumn.Insert
Selection.EntireColumn.Insert
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "YoY% Change"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "3 Year CAGR"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-1]-RC[2])/RC[2],"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-2]/RC[2])^(1/3)-1,"""")"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Range("A1:B1").Select
ActiveCell.AutoFill Range("A1:B" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("A1:B" & LastRow).Select

End Sub
```

Since incorporating the LastRow variable I have not been able to run the code.

Instead it returns a run-time error

> Autofill method of range class failed

when debugging. How should I autofill and end the code?

Comment: Which cell is selected when you start the macro?  (It's very hard for people to debug if you use `Selection` and don't specify in the question what is selected.)  Also, what is the value of `LastRow` when it crashes? (i.e. which row contains the last used cell in column A of the active sheet?)

Comment: My guess (and it is a **very** wild guess) is that you are trying to do `ActiveCell.Range("A1:B1").AutoFill ActiveCell.Resize(LastRow - 1, 2), Type:=xlFillDefault`, but this is a **very bad** way of doing things so, if you tell us what you are trying to achieve (perhaps add a screenshot of your worksheet to the question), we might be able to help you fix things so that it is more robust.

Comment: I think I'm right in saying you can only autofill in one sense at a time, ie columns then rows or vice versa. Try the line twice: once "A1:A?" and then the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is unclear on where you actually start (e.g. what cell Selection is), I suppose that it could be assumed that you know what you are doing before running the sub procedure. In any event, it is better to .FillDown or simply write the formulas all at once.

Using .FillDown:

```
Sub addColumnsandChange()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Finds the value of the last row
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Selection.Cells(1)
        .Resize(lastRow, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
        .Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 2) = Array("YoY% Change", "3 Year CAGR")
        .Offset(1, -2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-1]-RC[2])/RC[2], TEXT(,))"
        .Offset(1, -1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-2]/RC[2])^(1/3)-1, TEXT(,))"
        .Offset(1, -2).Resize(lastRow - 1, 2).FillDown
        .Offset(0, -2).Resize(lastRow, 2).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Writing all formulas at once:

```
Sub addColumnsandChange()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Finds the value of the last row
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    With Selection.Cells(1)
        .Resize(lastRow, 2).EntireColumn.Insert
        .Offset(0, -2).Resize(1, 2) = Array("YoY% Change", "3 Year CAGR")
        .Offset(1, -2).Resize(lastRow - 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-1]-RC[2])/RC[2], TEXT(,))"
        .Offset(1, -1).Resize(lastRow - 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR((RC[-2]/RC[2])^(1/3)-1, TEXT(,))"
        .Offset(0, -2).Resize(lastRow, 2).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to autofill starting with the first row.

However, the formulas you are trying to copy are on the second row. Your first row contains header text.

**Please note:** You don't have to Select a cell before changing it's value. Your code would perform *much* faster if you would leave our those Selects. (And the code would become much easier to read and understand)